# Colour replacement tool wont target certain items - Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

Im trying to colour replace the highlighted areas in the screen shot below, but when i use the colour replacement tool it dosnt seem to be able to colour these areas, any ideas ?

[image: image with areas to be replaced marqueed]

Ive also attached the full image below for reference

[image: full image for reference]

Comment: are you sure you have the actual image layer selected when you hit the tool?

Comment: You know you still have to select the color range inside the replace tool right? I mean you don't even really need to select it with marquee, or you could select it with marquee and paste it onto a new layer to isolate it, then replace the color on the duplicate layer..

Comment: @Ryan that's even a better solution, for it's nondestructive.

Comment: This rep ain't just for the good looks @Vincent - just don't know if Sam did that in which case this might be a technical support issue.

Comment: @Ryan + vincent ive set the tool as per the below screencast - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XoTTzOJIkj8&feature=youtu.be - whats odd is that it seems to be working with the red in the video and also a tiny bit with the grey, but by no means full coverage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't affect lightness so it just can't be seen on the nearly white fence. It's working as intended though.

My suggestion:

1. Select the top of the fence
2. Copy
3. Paste
4. Select the new layer
5. Image > Adjust > Exposure -- reduce exposure a bit
6. Select color replacement tool like you were and do what you were doing.